# Make CSV escape Double Quotation Marks

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, arcmap

I need to prepare a .csv file so that a double quotation marks gets ignored by the program processing it (ArcMap).  Arc was blending the contents of all following cells on that line into any previous one containing double quotation marks.  For example:

[image]

...and no further rows would get processed at all.

How does one make a CSV escape Double Quotation Marks for successful processing in ArcMap (10.2)?

Comment: Please show what the CSV looks like. Does it have something like `3,"158... 24"" metal",46.2378,...`?

Comment: Are my screen grabs not clear?  Thank you.

Comment: Your screenshots show the interpretation by the program you're using, which unfortunately doesn't say much about what's actually in there.

Comment: Actually, the first screen shot is before it gets processed.  I'm just showing the relevant column and the ones after because that's what is affected.

Comment: The problem is ArcMap. You can't control how it interprets things. You just have to go along with how it needs the data to be. I don't personally use ArcMap, and I don't know what it's doing. The best choice would be to use a format other than CSV if ArcMap accepts something else. If you want to try the character replacement strategy, I would go for `”` (the Right Double Quotation Mark; a.k.a. the closing quotes in a "smart quotes" pair). This might not work if (a) you really needed the straight quotes for some reason, or (b) ArcMap has a problem with characters beyond "safe" ASCII.

Comment: @Waterman Please open the CSV file in a text editor (Notepad, Sublime, etc.) and paste the line from there. The first screenshot only shows how the program you opened it in understood that line. (You can always [edit] the question)

Comment: @Norrius  OK, I've edited my question with the problem line opened in Notepad.

Comment: @JohnY  A good idea but when I bring the .csv into ArcMap it just turns the "smart quotes" into a regular "straight quotes".

Comment: This is quite interesting and weird. Are those really spaces and not tabs? (You can *sort of* tell in Notepad by moving the cursor around to see if you ever seem to "jump" multiple spaces, but to really be sure, you need either a hex editor or a programmer's editor which can show different symbols to mark spaces versus tabs. Or you could use Python itself.) Also, where are you getting the CSV from? Does it *have to* be a CSV?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say `df` is the DataFrame created for the csv files as follows

```
df = pd.read_csv('filename.csv')
```

Let us assume that `comments` is the name of the column where the issue occurs, i.e. you want to replace every double quotes (") with a null string ().

The following one-liner does that for you. It will replace every double quotes for every row in `df['comments']` with null string.

```
df['comments'] = df['comments'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('"', ''))
```

The lambda captures every row in `df['comments']` in variable `x`.

EDIT: To escape the double quotes you need to convert the string to it's raw format. Again another one-liner very similar to the one above.

```
df['comments'] = df['comments'].apply(lambda x: r'{0}'.format(x))
```

The `r` before the string is an escape to escape characters in python.

Comment: I appreciate your answer.  Except I don't want to replace the double quotes with blank.  This will effectively delete the double quotes, correct?  I just want to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Thanks.  Which part of your code is telling the .csv to escape all double quotation marks?

Comment: Also, can you confirm what the zero in "r'{0}'" is doing?

Comment: The `r` before the quotes for a string is a check for the string saying, do not consider escape characters for eg. If I want to print `\n`, I cannot simple `print('\n')` because it will print a newline. In that case I do `print(r'\n')`.

Comment: The `0` says replace the 0th indexed element in format, i.e. `x`

Comment: OK, I'll give it a shot.  And the "pd" refers to the "Pandas" module, correct?

Comment: Yes `import pandas as pd`

Comment: Thank you for your effort.  Unfortunately I have come to discover the python library in my version of the software I'm using (ArcMap) does not have the Pandas module.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reading the file with the `csv` module and writing it back in the hopes that the output format will be more digestible for your other tool. See the docs for [formatting options](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#dialects-and-formatting-parameters).

```
import csv
with open('in.csv', 'r') as fin, open('out.csv', 'w') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    # alternative:
    # writer = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t', escapechar='\\', doublequote=False)
    for line in reader:
        writer.writerow(line)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I executed your suggestion and got a surprising result.  Please see my edited question for the specific output.

Comment: @Waterman That looks odd, but I'm afraid you'll have to debug this yourself because I don't know what the original data was. You could try changing the formatting flags.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was writing a module to do some "pre-processing" of the CSV file as follows.  The key line is where the "writer" has the parameter "quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL".  Hopefully this is useful to others.

```
def work(Source_CSV):
    from __main__ import *
    import csv, arcpy, os

    # Derive name and location for newly-formatted .csv file
    Head = os.path.split(Source_CSV)[0]
    Tail = os.path.split(Source_CSV)[1]
    name = Tail[:-4]
    new_folder = "formatted"
    new_path = os.path.join(Head,new_folder)
    Formatted_CSV = os.path.join(new_path,name+"_formatted.csv")
    #arcpy.AddMessage("Formatted_CSV = "+Formatted_CSV)

    # Populate the new .csv file with quotation marks around all field contents ("quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL")
    with open(Source_CSV, 'rb') as file1, open(Formatted_CSV,'wb') as file2:

        # Instantiate the .csv reader
        reader = csv.reader(file1, skipinitialspace=True)   

        # Write column headers without quotes
        headers = reader.next()  # 'next' function actually begins at the first row of the .csv.  
        str1 = ''.join(headers)
        writer = csv.writer(file2)
        writer.writerow(headers)

        # Write all other rows wrapped in double quotes
        writer = csv.writer(file2, delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

        # Write all other rows, at first quoting none...
        #writer = csv.writer(file2, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE,quotechar='\x01')

        for row in reader:
            # ...then manually doubling double quotes and wrapping 3rd column in double quotes.
            #row[2] = '"' + row[2].replace('"','""') + '"'
            writer.writerow(row) 

        return Formatted_CSV
```